# How to enable vi mode in geth console? (readline's inputrc not honored)

Tags: go-ethereum

Does the geth console input prompt use the standard readline library?

For apps that do, setting in `~/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

enables vi mode on the command prompt. For example, try

```
$ python
input()
```

with and without the above `~/.inputrc`.

Geth `Geth/v1.4.5-stable-a269a713/linux/go1.6.2` does not seem to honor the .inputrc setting. Missing feature (or bug)?

Comment: never thought of that, quite interested as well !

Comment: You never need `vi` there

Comment: @niksmac It's not about vi, it's about keyboard keymappings for editting the command line. Once you switch to vi mode, everything else becomes painful to use.

Comment: editing the command line? what is there for you to edit? out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

`geth` does not use the Unix standard readline library. It implements some of the command line input within it's code base with the [github.com/peterh/liner](https://github.com/peterh/liner) library for some of the other functionality.

**Q**: How to enable vi mode in geth console?

**A**: You cannot enable vi mode in the `geth` console.

**Q**: Geth `Geth/v1.4.5-stable-a269a713/linux/go1.6.2` does not seem to honor the .inputrc setting. Missing feature (or bug)?

**A**: I would consider this a feature, as `geth` has been built to run across the three operating systems Linux, OS X and Windows.

---

### Details

You will get the interactive console when you start `geth` with the `console` or `attach` command and these call `repl.interactive()`:

- See `func console(...)` in [cmd/geth/main.go, lines 358-387](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/geth/main.go#L358-L387) for the `console` command.
- See `func attach(...)` in [cmd/geth/main.go, lines 302-329](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/geth/main.go#L302-L329) for the `attach` command.

The calls to `repl.interactive()` execute the function `interactive()` in [cmd/geth/js.go, lines 318-371](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/geth/js.go#L318-L371).

The function `interactive()` uses the [cmd/utils/input.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/input.go) and [github.com/peterh/liner](https://github.com/peterh/liner) library to deal with the command line editor.

You can see the keystroke handling in [github.com/peterh/liner/input.go](https://github.com/peterh/liner/blob/master/input.go).