# What are the command line editing keys in geth's console

Tags: go-ethereum

What keys are available for editing the command line in `geth console`?

This is a follow-on question from the answer to [How to enable vi mode in geth console? (readline's inputrc not honored)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/how-to-enable-vi-mode-in-geth-console-readlines-inputrc-not-honored) and [Is there something like `help` or `dir` on the geth console?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/is-there-something-like-help-or-dir-on-the-geth-console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the available editing key combinations, from [github.com/peterh/liner/README.md](https://github.com/peterh/liner/blob/master/README.md):

[image]